# Facebook API FB.getLoginStatus returns undefined

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-like, app-id

I have added a like button on my website, and want to know who clicked the like button.
These are my sample code:

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({appId: '182722795115444', status: true, cookie: true,
                 xfbml: true});

        // To find who clicked the like button
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response){
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

                if (response.session) {
                    // logged in and connected user, someone you know
                    alert("logged in and connected user");
                } else {
                    // no user session available, someone you dont know
                    alert("no user session available");
                }
            });
        });
      };
      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
          '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
    </script>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=182722795115444&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
    <fb:like href="www.blogcountry.net" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" font=""></fb:like>
```

When I clicked the Like button, and login facebook, do like successfully, but got "no user session available" alert.

So I am confused:

1. My appId in FB.init is the same as
   fb:like tag, is it right?
2. Are there something wrong in my
   program ?
3. How to get user name who click the
   Like button?

Thanks in advance.

---

### **Update:**

@OffBySome Thanks for your answer.

You means I must call FB authenticate API, then I could get the user's info? 
But...in [facebook development doc](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) FAQ:

---

> How do I know when a user clicks a
>   Like button?
>
> If you are using the XFBML version of
>   the button, you can subscribe to the
>   'edge.create' event through
>   [FB.Event.subscribe](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/).

---

So, It means I cannot know who clicks the Like Button, just know the button is clicked.

If I want to get user's info, I must implement the login action before click Like?
It's really bad userbility.

Could anyone give a good idea to resolve it...

Comment: possible duplicate of [FB.getLoginStatus inside edge.create callback is returning unknown status and null session after logging in from the popup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108290/fb-getloginstatus-inside-edge-create-callback-is-returning-unknown-status-and-nu)

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure you won't get a Facebook session just by liking a page.  You normally only get a user Facebook session when they authenticate with your application (for example, with `<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true"></fb:login-button>`) .  If do an an `alert(JSON.stringify(response));` inside that function what values do you get?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You means I must call FB authenticate API, then I could get the user's info? But...in [facebook development doc](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) FAQ: ----------
> How do I know when a user clicks a
> Like button?
> > If you are using the XFBML version of
> the button, you can subscribe to the
> 'edge.create' event through
> [FB.Event.subscribe](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/). ---------- So, It means I cannot know who clicks the Like Button, just know the button is clicked. If I want t

Comment: basically yes. to know who a user is, they need to approve your app.

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) 
{                   
alert('You just liked '+href);  

    session = FB.getSession();
    uid = session['uid'];
    alert(uid);

});
```